# path expression with slug tag other than using url in django

Tags: django, url, path, tags, slug

I want to express path rather than urls
but I am not sure the following codes are correct
I think it does not work home/blog/posts

I have constructed blog web programming using django so I exptected post page to pop up nicely but actually it didn't. I tired several times and searched for it in google but I did not gain what I expected.

```
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import *

url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', PostDV.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
   => path('post/(<slug:>[-w]+)/', PostDV.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

 url('tag/?P<tag>[^/]+(?u)/',PostTOL.as_view(),name='tagged_object_list'),
 =?path('tag/<tag:>[^/]+(?u)/',PostTOL.as_view(),name='tagged_object_list'),
```

there are no messages on command line on window as below when I ran runserver

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). January 15, 2019 -
>   01:43:13 Django version 2.1.4, using settings 'plateform.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
>   with CTRL-BREAK. [15/Jan/2019 01:43:24] "GET /admin/blog/post/
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 6863 [15/Jan/2019 01:43:24] "GET /admin/jsi18n/
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 3185

Comment: You are importing path, but using url.

Comment: I imported path. As I said, I want to use path instead of url. "=>" in the above means I want to use path rather than url. but it does not work properly as shown below question.